# openshift new-app does not respect --source-secret

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3

The below command still prompts me for typing in username and password. I would expect it to start building without the prompt as i'm mentioning the source secret.

```
oc new-app --strategy=docker --code=https://git.abcd.mycompany.com/project/openshift-pipeline-trail.git#development --name=openshift-pipeline --source-secret=robot-cred
```

I also tried linking the source secret by the below command, still it prompts me for username and password.

```
oc secrets link builder robot-cred
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your `Secret` does not have the right format and can therefore not be used by `oc new-app`. How did you create the secret?

Note that only the following types of secrets can be used as a source secret ([Source Clone Secrets](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-clone-secrets)):

- .gitconfig File
- Basic Authentication
- SSH Key Authentication
- Trusted Certificate Authorities

So to have Source Clone Secret with Basic Auth, create the secret like so:

```
oc create secret generic <secret_name> \
    --from-literal=username=<user_name> \
    --from-literal=password=<password> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/basic-auth
```

Comment: Hi @Simon, thanks for your answer. I created the secret via the GUI and yes I can confirm that it is a `source secret` with `basic-auth` and the type is `kubernetes.io/basic-auth`. The weird thing is that, when I use the "deploy using dockerfile" via the GUI with the same secret, it works absolutely fine but with the CLI oc command, it  prompts me for the creds.

Comment: Good to hear. Can you maybe add the output of the command with `-v=7` to get detailed debugging output (see https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#troubleshooting-cli)? Potentially we can see something in the debug output.

Comment: same here 

`oc new-app --image-stream=php:5.5 --strategy=source --code=https://<private-bitbucket-repo>/git/web_cn.git --context-dir=php-webcn --source-secret=vajra-bitbucket`  


is still trying to clone and analyse the repo,  prompting for bitbucket credentials 

while the short hand method  below works as expected 
i.e without prompting credentials 

`oc new-app php:5.5~https://<private-bitbucket-repo>/git//web_cn.git --context-dir=php-webcn --source-secret=vajra-bitbucket`